# libgif not working on Shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes, lib

I am trying to use the shoes framework with ruby.  I ran the .run file from the website and installed it.  When I try to use ./shoes I get the error `error while loading shared libraries: libgif.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`  Any idea on how I can fix this problem.

Comment: please include clear description of the issue and the code you implemented. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?newreg=602733c460564082957a56ec29144357

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: That error means that either libgif isn't installed or it can't be found on your system.